# What did I do wrong when I solved this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\frac{dy}{dx}=y\sec^2x$ and $y=5$ when $x=0$, then $y=$?
A) $e^{\tan x} + 4$

B) $e^{\tan x} + 4$

C) $5e^{\tan x}$

D) $\tan x +5$

E) $\tan x + 5e^x$

This is how I solved it:

$\frac{dy}{y}=\sec^2x dx$

$\int \frac{dy}{y}= \int \sec^2x dx$

$\ln|y|= \tan x +C$

$e^{\ln|y|}=e^{\tan x}+C$

$|y|=e^{\tan x} + C$

$y=\pm (e^{\tan x} + C)$

Since $y=5$ we choose $y=e^{\tan x} + C$

But the answer is C)

I know that I can find $dy/dx$ for each answer choice and C) is the only one that fits.. however I don't know what I did wrong in my solution.

Comment: You have $ln|y|=\tan x+C$. When you exponentiate you should get $|y|=e^{\tan 
x+C}=C_1e^{\tan x}$

Answer (score 1):

When you take the exponential function, you actually get
$$
|y|=e^{\tan x}e^C
$$
or
$$
y=De^{\tan x}
$$
where $D=\pm e^C\ne 0$.Since $y=0$ is also a solution, you can include $D=0$ to get the general solution. Finally, you impose the given initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you made a mistake

> $\ln|y|= \tan x +C$
>
> $e^{\ln|y|}=e^{\tan x}+C$

If $\ln|y|= \tan x +C$, after exponentiation you get $e^{\ln|y|}=e^{\tan x+C}$